# Spark scala - find non-zero rows in a df

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have more than 100 columns in a dataframe. Out of 100 columns, 90 are metric columns. I need to find rows that has atleast one of the metric is not 0. I am filtering something like metric1 <> 0 or metric2 <> 0 and so on.. is there any trick to handle the situation better ?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some more options, all presuming that the target columns have names such as `metric1, metric2, metric3 ... metricN`.

First let's identify the target columns:

```
val targetColumns = df.columns.filter(_.matches("metric\d+"))
```

**Option1:** Filter using [greatest](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#greatest) which will return the column with the larger value:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.greatest

df.filter(greatest(targetColumns:_*) != 0)
```

**Option2:** Applying bitwise OR between columns:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val bitwiseORCols = targetColumns.map(col).reduce(_ bitwiseOR _)

df.filter(bitwiseORCols != 0)
```

Comment: Options 1 and 2 assume that all values are non-negative. This might be ok for columns named "metric", but could be mentioned in the answer. About option 2+3: the filter columns  start with ~90 opening brackets. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: To be honest I wouldn't care about opening brackets unless I retrieve some weird warning from Spark. One alternative is to use string expression instead as you did in your answer but with plus and or accordingly.

Comment: @werner I removed the option of sum since it might end up with 0 in the case of mixed negative non negative values. I also replaced `> 0` with `!=0`. Thank you for the useful remarks

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array column from your metrics columns and use an udf to check exists non zero values in that array column you created.

```
scala> df.show
+---+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| id| name|metric1|metric2|metric3|
+---+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1|name1|      3|      0|      0|
|  2|name2|      0|      0|      0|
|  3|name3|      0|      3|      3|
|  4|name4|      0|      0|      0|
+---+-----+-------+-------+-------+


scala> def arrayNotAllZeros[T](a: Seq[T]):Boolean = {
     |   a.exists(_ != 0)
     | } 
arrayNotAllZeros: [T](a: Seq[T])Boolean

scala> 

scala> val myUdf = udf { arrayNotAllZeros[Int] _ }
myUdf: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,BooleanType,Some(List(ArrayType(IntegerType,false))))

scala> 

scala> val metricCols = df.columns.takeRight(3)
metricCols: Array[String] = Array(metric1, metric2, metric3)

scala> df.withColumn("nonZeroRow", myUdf(array(metricCols.head, metricCols.tail:_*))).show
+---+-----+-------+-------+-------+----------+
| id| name|metric1|metric2|metric3|nonZeroRow|
+---+-----+-------+-------+-------+----------+
|  1|name1|      3|      0|      0|      true|
|  2|name2|      0|      0|      0|     false|
|  3|name3|      0|      3|      3|      true|
|  4|name4|      0|      0|      0|     false|
+---+-----+-------+-------+-------+----------+
```